# Get text before/after cursor, on currently edited line, in TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

I can print out *all* text before and after the cursor using this code:

```dart
controller = TextEditingController();
final selection = controller.value.selection;
final text = controller.value.text;
print("\nBEFORE\n${selection.textBefore(text)}");
print("\nAFTER\n${selection.textAfter(text)}\n");
```

How can I use the `TextEditingController` to find only the text before/after the cursor *on the same line as the cursor*?

[image: TextField with line of lin<<cursor>>e2 contents]

For example, I want to use the `TextEditingController` to query the text before/after the current position of the cursor so the text before is "lin" and the text after the cursor is "e2 contents" (in the image above).

Full app code that gets *all* text before/after the cursor (not on the same line as required):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: TextFieldApp()));

class TextFieldApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextFieldAppState createState() => _TextFieldAppState();
}

class _TextFieldAppState extends State<TextFieldApp> {
  TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        controller: controller,
        maxLines: 10,
        maxLength: null,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TextEditingController();
    controller.text = 'line 1\nline2 contents\nline3';
    controller.addListener(() {
      final selection = controller.value.selection;
      final text = controller.value.text;
      print("\nBEFORE\n${selection.textBefore(text)}");
      print("\nAFTER\n${selection.textAfter(text)}\n");
    });
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can split the text you got `var data = selection.textBefore(text).split('\n');` then take the last value from the array. Similarly the first entry for the text after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the text by a `\n` then take the last value from the array.
Similarly the first entry for the text after.

```dart
final selection = controller.value.selection;
final text = controller.value.text;
final before = selection.textBefore(text);
final after = selection.textAfter(text);
print(before.split('\n').last);
print(after.split('\n').first);
```

Note:

If the users selects `cont` in a line with content `line2 contents` they would be

```
line2 //before
ents  //after
```

If you need the text 'after' to also have the 'selected text',
you may add the text 'inside' to the text 'after'.

```dart
selection.textInside(text) + after.split('\n').first;
```